# How to rank a variable in a column based on a conditional, when there are NAs in the column

Tags: r, dplyr, na, rank

I have a longitudinal data set with two people in which the rows of data are numbered as 'episodes', and some episodes have a test 'result'. The goal of the below code is to:

1. Create binary variable 'sup' to evaluate a 'result'. If result == NA, then sup == NA. This code works.
2. Create sup_rank to enumerate the occurrence of sup == 1 within people who had an occurrence of sup==1. In other words, I want to know if this is the first time, second time, etc. that sup==1. **Problem:** This code currently does not work since person 2's first sup==1 is ranked as '2' (when it should be ranked as '1').
3. Create an event variable that:

- equals 1 if sup_rank==1
- equals 0 if sup == 0 **OR** sup_rank does not equal 1
- equals NA if sup (and thus sup_rank) equals NA

Currently I tried to do #3 in two steps with event and event final. **Problem:** it does not work because 'sup_rank' does not work, but regardless, it would be ideal to create 'event' as one variable (and not need an 'event_final').

```r
#Load packages
pacman::p_load(dplyr)

#Create variables for data set 
person <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
episode <- c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
result <- c(NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 2, NA, 2, NA, 2)

#Populate data frame with variables
d <- cbind(person, episode, result)
d <- as.data.frame(d)

#Manipulate data frame to create 4 new variables
d1 <- d %>%
  #Need to create new variables within each person
  group_by(person) %>%
  #Need to correctly order the rows of data before creating the variables
  arrange(person, episode) %>%
  #Create variable to evaluate 'result'
  mutate(sup = if_else(result == 2, 1, 0, NA_real_)) %>%
  #if sup == 1, rank it
  mutate(sup_rank = ifelse(sup == 1, rank(sup == 1, na.last = 'keep', ties.method = 'first'), NA_real_)) %>%
  #create an event if the rank of the sup == 1 is equal to 1 (we want the initial suppression)
  mutate(event = if_else(sup_rank == 1, 1, 0, NA_real_)) %>%
  #now override the value of event to be equal to 0 if sup==0
  mutate(event_final = if_else(sup == 0, 0, event)) %>%
  arrange(person, episode)

print(d1)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 7
#> # Groups:   person [2]
#>    person episode result   sup sup_rank event event_final
#>     <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>
#>  1      1       1     NA    NA       NA    NA          NA
#>  2      1       2     NA    NA       NA    NA          NA
#>  3      2       1     NA    NA       NA    NA          NA
#>  4      2       2      1     0       NA    NA           0
#>  5      2       3     NA    NA       NA    NA          NA
#>  6      2       4      2     1        2     0           0
#>  7      2       5     NA    NA       NA    NA          NA
#>  8      2       6      2     1        3     0           0
#>  9      2       7     NA    NA       NA    NA          NA
#> 10      2       8      2     1        4     0           0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

There is a more efficient way to do this for sure, but in the meantime, here's a solution I created:

```r
#Load packages
pacman::p_load(dplyr)

#Create variables for data set 
person <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
episode <- c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
result <- c(NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 2, NA, 2, NA, 2)

#Populate data frame with variables
d <- cbind(person, episode, result)
d <- as.data.frame(d)

#Manipulate data frame to create 5 new variables
d1 <- d %>%
  #Need to create new variables within each person
  group_by(person) %>%
  #Need to correctly order the rows of data before creating the variables
  arrange(person, episode) %>%
  #Create variable to evaluate 'result'
  mutate(sup = if_else(result == 2, 1, 0, NA_real_)) %>%
  #Create a flag for each time sup==1
  mutate(sup_flag = if_else(sup == 1, 1, NA_real_, NA_real_)) %>%
  #if sup == 1, rank it
  mutate(sup_rank = ifelse(sup == 1, rank(sup_flag, na.last = 'keep', ties.method = 'first'), NA_real_)) %>%
  #create an event if the rank of the sup == 1 is equal to 1 (we want the initial suppression)
  mutate(event = if_else(sup_rank == 1, 1, 0, NA_real_)) %>%
  #now override the value of event to be equal to 0 if sup==0
  mutate(event_final = if_else(sup == 0, 0, event)) %>%
  arrange(person, episode)

print(d1)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 8
#> # Groups:   person [2]
#>    person episode result   sup sup_flag sup_rank event event_final
#>     <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>
#>  1      1       1     NA    NA       NA       NA    NA          NA
#>  2      1       2     NA    NA       NA       NA    NA          NA
#>  3      2       1     NA    NA       NA       NA    NA          NA
#>  4      2       2      1     0       NA       NA    NA           0
#>  5      2       3     NA    NA       NA       NA    NA          NA
#>  6      2       4      2     1        1        1     1           1
#>  7      2       5     NA    NA       NA       NA    NA          NA
#>  8      2       6      2     1        1        2     0           0
#>  9      2       7     NA    NA       NA       NA    NA          NA
#> 10      2       8      2     1        1        3     0           0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>